# How to scale and translate imageview and edittext together?

Tags: android, animation

In my layout file, I have an ImageView, an EditTExt and a Button, aligned vertically. My requirement is,  on button click, ImageView size should reduce to 50% and move to top left corner, and EditText should move to top right corder. Both should appear in same line. This translation should be animated and played together. Have tried scale and translate animation. But no luck. After scaling ImageView occupies original size.

Layout File :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cover_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/quila2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cover_image"
        android:text="Headline"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Animation :

```
   ` int top = mLayout.getTop();
    int bottom = mLayout.getBottom();
    int left = mLayout.getLeft();
    int right = mLayout.getRight();`
```

For Image :

```
 ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.5f, 1, 0.5f, 1, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    scaleAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
    mCoverImage.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);`
```

}

For EditText :

```
  TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(left,   right- mCoverImage.getWidth(), top, bottom - mCoverImage.getHeight());
    translateAnimation.setDuration(4000);
    translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mEdiText.startAnimation(translateAnimation);`
```

Anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's see some code.

Comment: Please note that Android animations are only applied to view's bitmap and do not affect view's boundaries.

Comment: Can we change orientation through animation?